# Including 'conversion_specs' parameter, or 'user_os' field in targeting spec parameter, causes error

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

My question is about the Facebook Ads API and the fields 'user_os', 'user_device' in the parameter `targeting` in Ad Group creation, as well as 'conversion_specs'.

I can successfully make an Ad Group, but a very simple one with objective Website Clicks and the bare minimum in other parameters. I am trying to create a Mobile App Installs ad.

My parameters:

```
"access_token": <access_token>
"campaign_id": <set_id>,
"creative": {"creative_id": <creative_id>},
"objective": 'MOBILE_APP_INSTALLS',
"bid_type": 'CPM',
"bid_info": {"IMPRESSIONS": 3},
"conversion_specs": {
"action.type": 'mobile_app_install',
    "application": <app_id>
},
"tracking_specs": {
    "action.type": 'mobile_app_install',
    "application": <app_id>
},
"targeting": {
    "user_os": 'iOS',
    "user_device": 'iPhone'
    "custom_audiences": [{'id': <custom_audience_id>}]
},
"name": "noNameProvided",
"adgroup_status": 'PAUSED'
```

`<app_id>` is my Facebook App ID which points to the iTunes store ID of Facebook's mobile app itself, because I'm just testing and don't have a mobile app of my own.

When "user_os" and "user_device" are included, or "conversion_specs" is included, I get

`{'error': {'message': 'An unknown error has occurred.', 'code': 1, 'type': 'OAuthException'}}`,

and when I EXCLUDE "user_os" and "user_device" and "conversion_specs", I get

```
{'error': {'code': 1487504, 'message': "Please include a value for 'user_os' or 'user_device' in ad targeting spec.", 'is_transient': False, 'type': 'Exception'}}
```

Any insight on why this is? "conversion_specs" and targeting fields "user_os" and "user_device" seem to be the things breaking this Ad Group creation, but I cannot tell what I am doing wrong with them.

EDIT - The creative parameters I am using are shown below:

```
"object_store_url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id284882215",
"image_hash": <img_hash>, # 1200 x 627 .jpg
"name": "install_c",
"body": "installing is good",
"call_to_action_type": "LISTEN_MUSIC",
"actor_name": "alphadtrib"
"actor_image_hash": <another_img_hash> # 75 x 75 .jpg
```

Comment: The tracking spec needs to have a Facebook app id, not the iTunes store ID. Even if you don't have a mobile app of your own, use the app id of the Facebook app

Comment: we're also working on improving the error messages so you don't just receive an unknown error response.

Comment: Ooh, that'd be wonderful! Verbosity is a developer's best friend :)

Answer (score 3):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/mobile-app-ads

```
For mobile ads, when using the creative ID in the ad group you must specify 
a tracking and conversion spec explicitly using the Facebook App ID. To obtain 
an app ID, register the app on Facebook.
```

As you use itunes store ID, this is what might be breaking it

EDIT:

OK, I tried using the spec you have posted, user_device and user_os need to be arrays, not strings :) When I changed them to arrays it worked for me

EDIT2:

Your creative is also wrong. 
According to developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/mobile-app-ads you have to create an unpublished page post by sending request to graph.facebook.com{page_id}/feed with fields:

message, call_to_action, picture

Then, you create a creative, passing object_story_id:

```
// create the ad creative first 
curl \ 
-F "object_story_id=1776318_101523207386" \ 
-F "access_token=_____" \ 
graph.facebook.com/act_{ad_account_id}/adcreatives
```

Comment: Shoot, I miswrote that. <app_id> is my Facebook app ID, which points to the iTunes ID of Facebook's mobile app. I will edit.

Comment: Can you post what your creative looks like? There were recent changes to the creative for mobile app ads, so you might be using the legacy one

Comment: Edited the original comment - use arrays for user_device and user_os and it should work

Comment: your creative is also wrong. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/mobile-app-ads you have to create an unpublished page post by sending request to https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed with fields:
message, call_to_action, picture

Then, you create a creative, passing object_story_id
// create the ad creative first
curl \
-F "object_story_id=1776318_101523207386" \
-F "access_token=_____" \
https://graph.facebook.com/act_{ad_account_id}/adcreatives

Comment: Hmm ok. I didn't see that anywhere in the Ads API docs, do you think it still applies to non-manual ad creation? (I am waiting on something so will be able to actually test it all out myself soon, but in the mean time just trying to gather all the info I can.)